# R tick data : merging date and time into a single object

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, finance

I'm currently working in tick data with R and I would like to merge date and time into a single object as I need to get a precise time object to compute some statistics on my data. Here is how my data looks like:

```
               date       time      price flag    exchange
2   XXH10   2010-02-02   08:00:03   2787 1824        E
3   XXH10   2010-02-02   08:00:04   2786    3        E
4   XXH10   2010-02-02   08:00:04   2787    6        E
5   XXH10   2010-02-02   08:00:04   2787    1        E
6   XXH10   2010-02-02   08:00:04   2787    1        E
```

Basically, I would like to merge the columns "date" and "time" into a single one.

Comment: If you specify which statistics, someone might come up with a better solution than merging date and time.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Create a `datetime` object with `as.POSIXct`:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(x$date, x$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2010-02-02 08:00:03 GMT" "2010-02-02 08:00:04 GMT" "2010-02-02 08:00:04 GMT"
[4] "2010-02-02 08:00:04 GMT" "2010-02-02 08:00:04 GMT"
```

Comment: @user1474263 you should click the check-mark on this answer if it answers your question.

Comment: arguably, there is always more elegant way in R using specialized packages - in this case **lubridate**.

Comment: Or just `with(x, as.POSIXct(paste(date, time)))`

Answer (score 17):

Of course, more elegant solution (arguably) is possible with extra package. When working with dates it's **lubridate** package:

```
library(lubridate)

with(x, ymd(date) + hms(time))
```

should produce *POSIXlt* vector.

UPDATE:

There is another solution using general purpose date and time conversion package `anytime` (based on C++ library [Boost date_time](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time.html)):

```
 library(anytime)

 with(x, anytime(paste(date, time)))
```

Indeed, comparing `anytime` with both base R and `lubridate` (deservedly considered rather slow - see [Why are my functions on lubridate dates so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46046714/59470)) C++ (`anytime`) wins:

```
 x = read.csv(text = 'date,time
2010-02-02,08:00:03
2010-02-02,08:00:04
2010-02-02,08:00:04
2010-02-03,08:00:04
2010-02-04,08:00:05
2010-02-04,08:00:05
2010-02-04,08:00:06
2010-02-04,08:00:07
2010-02-04,08:00:08
2010-02-04,08:00:14')

 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   base = with(x, as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
   anytime = with(x, anytime::anytime(paste(date, time))),
   lubri = with(x, lubridate::ymd(date) + lubridate::hms(time)),
   times = 1000L
)
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>   expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq        max  neval
>  base       71.163   91.2555   104.38747  104.785  112.1185   256.997  1000
>  anytime    40.508   52.5385   63.46973   61.843   68.5730    221.076  1000
>  lubri      1596.490 1850.4400 2235.34254 1909.588 2033.096   110751.622  1000
> ```

Comment: From my experience, `ymd` and `hms` are way slower than other options where you provide the format manually. So when working with large data, I would recommend `as.POSIXct` (or `fasttime::fastPOSIXct`).

Comment: added `anytime` solution with benchmarks that show `anytime` runs the fastest.