# Convert data into time stamps in R

Tags: r, date, time, timestamp, time-series

I have a data set with observations for a few month, where every day contains an observation for every hour (24 hours). There is a Date and a Time variable, and I would like to make a time stamp combining the two in order to predict the price as a timeseries. The data looks similar to this:

```
Date      Time      Price
05/apr    23-24     1798
05/apr    22-23     3452
05/apr    21-22     1224
05/apr    20-21     9483
05/apr    19-20     2345
05/apr    18-19     1235
05/apr    17-18     9281
05/apr    16-17     4953
05/apr    15-16     2342
05/apr    14-15     2345
05/apr    13-14     1235
05/apr    12-13     9281
05/apr    11-12     4953
05/apr    10-11     2342
```

I have tried `x <- as.Date(data$Date, format="%d/%b")`, but I am not sure about how to handle the time interval Time, so I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609252/r-tick-data-merging-date-and-time-into-a-single-object

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format = "%d/%b %H-%M", tz = "GMT")`

Comment: Thank you Roland!