# Convert multiple date column of a data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table

I am trying to convert multiple date columns (with different format) in `data.table`. There are few method already available. One of the link [Efficiently convert a date column in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078151/efficiently-convert-a-date-column-in-data-table). I was trying using `mapply`. But got the following error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`((paste0(dtVar, "*")),
> mapply(function(x,  :    Supplied 12 items to be assigned to 6 items
> of column 'X1*'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to
> make this intent clear to readers of your code.

```
library(data.table)

# sample data
df <- data.table(
  X1 = c("1996-01-04", "1996-01-05", "1996-01-08", "1996-01-09", "1996-01-10", "1996-01-11"), 
  X2 = c("02/01/1996", "03/01/1996", "04/01/1996", "05/01/1996", "08/01/1996", "09/01/1996"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# convert date columns
dtVar <- c("X1", "X2")
inDtFmt <- c("%Y-%m-%d","%d/%m/%Y")

df[,(dtVar) := mapply(function(x,y){strptime(df[[x]], format = y)}, dtVar, inDtFmt)]

## Further investigation
mm <- mapply(function(x,y){strptime(df[[x]], format = y)}, dtVar, inDtFmt)

str(mm)
List of 2
# $ X1: POSIXlt[1:6], format: "1996-01-04" "1996-01-05" "1996-01-08" "1996-01-09" ...
# $ X2: POSIXlt[1:6], format: "1996-01-02" "1996-01-03" "1996-01-04" "1996-01-05" ...
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapply` usually tries to simplify result into a vector, you should use `Map` instead. `strptime` returns object of class `POSIXlt`, here you need only date so use `as.Date`.

Moreover, if you use `lubridate::parse_date_time` you can do this with `lapply`.

```
library(data.table)

df[, (dtVar) := lapply(.SD, lubridate::parse_date_time, inDtFmt), .SDcols = dtVar]
df

#           X1         X2
#1: 1996-01-04 1996-01-02
#2: 1996-01-05 1996-01-03
#3: 1996-01-08 1996-01-04
#4: 1996-01-09 1996-01-05
#5: 1996-01-10 1996-01-08
#6: 1996-01-11 1996-01-09
```

Comment: Yes.. You are correct.. The there is no error when SIMPLIFY = F used in mapply..

Answer (score 1):

You can do using [`as.IDate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/IDateTime):

```
df <- df[,as.list(Map(function(x,y){as.IDate(.SD[[x]], format = y)}, dtVar, inDtFmt))]
print(df)

           X1         X2
1: 1996-01-04 1996-01-02
2: 1996-01-05 1996-01-03
3: 1996-01-08 1996-01-04
4: 1996-01-09 1996-01-05
5: 1996-01-10 1996-01-08
6: 1996-01-11 1996-01-09
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `anydate` from `anytime` which can automatically pick up the format and change to `Date` class

```
library(data.table)
library(anytime)
df[, (dtVar) := lapply(.SD, anydate), .SDcols = dtVar]

str(df)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ X1: Date, format: "1996-01-04" "1996-01-05" "1996-01-08" "1996-01-09" ...
# $ X2: Date, format: "1996-02-01" "1996-03-01" "1996-04-01" "1996-05-01" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
library(data.table)

# sample data
df <- data.table(
  X1 = c("1996-01-04", "1996-01-05", "1996-01-08", "1996-01-09", "1996-01-10", "1996-01-11"), 
  X2 = c("02/01/1996", "03/01/1996", "04/01/1996", "05/01/1996", "08/01/1996", "09/01/1996"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)

dtFmt <- list(X1 = "%Y-%m-%d", X2 = "%d/%m/%Y")

for (col in names(df)) {
  df[[col]] <- as.Date(df[[col]],  dtFmt[[col]]) 
}

str(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post code-only answers, you should include an explanation of how this code works and answers the question. This makes it more useful to the OP as well as other users with similar questions, so is more likely to be upvoted.