# as_datetime() Error: All formats failed to parse

Tags: r, date, time, paste

Why does as_datetime() result in NA in the below example?

```
x <- dmy("1-1-2000")
y <- "14:30"
as_datetime(paste(x, y))
```

Error:

```
[NA]
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using lubridate already, you just need to add the date object `dmy`to the time object (hour : min) by setting `hm` before.

```
x <- dmy("1-1-2000") 
y <- "14:30" 
z <- x + hm(y)
```

See : [R tick data : merging date and time into a single object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11609252/10580543)

Comment: Hello @tdel, thank you for the solution. I used this method on a dataframe and it worked for parsing two columns, however it is failing at the rows in which the times are at hour zero (ex. 00:34). Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

We can use the `format` argument

```
library(lubridate)
as_datetime(paste(x, y), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#[1] "2000-01-01 14:30:00 UTC"
```

---

Or another option is `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime(paste(x, y))
#[1] "2000-01-01 14:30:00 EST"
```

---

The reason could be that it expectss the time to be in `%H:%M:%S` format, which the 'y' is not.  If we use the full format instead of `%H:%M` (which can also be judged as `%M:%S`)

```
y1 <- "14:30:00"
as_datetime(paste(x, y1))
#[1] "2000-01-01 14:30:00 UTC"
```

NOTE: This answers why the OP get a warning message.