# How to aggregate the hourly rainfall data data into 24hr series

Tags: r

My data frame is as follows

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
              ~date, ~pcp,
   "9/27/2017 9:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 10:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 11:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 12:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 13:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 14:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 15:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 16:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 17:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 18:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 19:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 20:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 21:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 22:00",    0,
  "9/27/2017 23:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 0:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 1:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 2:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 3:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 4:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 5:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 6:00",    0,
   "9/28/2017 7:00", 0.15,
   "9/28/2017 8:00", 8.76,
   "9/28/2017 9:00", 0.02,
  "9/28/2017 10:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 11:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 12:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 13:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 14:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 15:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 16:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 17:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 18:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 19:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 20:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 21:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 22:00",    0,
  "9/28/2017 23:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 0:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 1:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 2:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 3:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 4:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 5:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 6:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 7:00",    0,
   "9/29/2017 8:00", 0.31
  )
```

I would like to have a daily aggregate of the data (sum). Instead of aggregating from 00:00 to 23:59 of the same day, I would like it with the initial time starting at 09:00 day `i` and ending at 08:59 of day `i + 1` (24 h later).

The output is desire is like the following

```
9/28/2017,8.91
9/29/2017,0.33
```

I did it manually in Excel, I'm  not sure what code to use for this problem.
The provided example is an extract of the long data frame.
Thanks...

Comment: Could you add more details about the output you're looking for?

Comment: So you want to sum the data of the entire day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data for each date

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate(datetime = parse_date_time(date, "mdy H:M"),
           date = date(datetime)) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(sum_pcp = sum(pcp))
```

Will produce

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date       sum_pcp
  <date>          <dbl>
1 2017-09-27       0   
2 2017-09-28       8.93
3 2017-09-29       0.31
```

If you want to count from 9:00 to 9:00 of the following day, you could introduce a `subjective_day` by subtracting 9 hours from the original `datetime` object.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(datetime = parse_date_time(date, "mdy H:M"),
         date = date(datetime),
         initial_day = date(first(date)),
         time = hour(datetime),
         subjective_day = datetime - hours(9)) %>%
  group_by(subjective_day = floor_date(subjective_day, "1 day")) %>% 
  summarise(sum_pcp = sum(pcp))
```

Will produce

```
  subjective_day      sum_pcp
  <dttm>                <dbl>
1 2017-09-27 00:00:00    8.91
2 2017-09-28 00:00:00    0.33
```

Your subjective day will always be 1 day behind, so you can just adjust for that or have in mind that somewhere with a 9 hour time difference in the world would actually have that as the correct datetime :)

Comment: Thanks alot the last option is the one I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Solution using base R and `data.table` (it often works better when performance matters or as alternative to `dplyr` and/or `lubridate`):

Step 1: setup and create R data frame

```
library(data.table)

mydt = fread(input = "date,pcp
 9/27/2017 9:00,0
 9/27/2017 10:00,0
 9/27/2017 11:00,0
 9/27/2017 12:00,0
 9/27/2017 13:00,0
 9/27/2017 14:00,0
 9/27/2017 15:00,0
 9/27/2017 16:00,0
 9/27/2017 17:00,0
 9/27/2017 18:00,0
 9/27/2017 19:00,0
 9/27/2017 20:00,0
 9/27/2017 21:00,0
 9/27/2017 22:00,0
 9/27/2017 23:00,0
 9/28/2017 0:00,0
 9/28/2017 1:00,0
 9/28/2017 2:00,0
 9/28/2017 3:00,0
 9/28/2017 4:00,0
 9/28/2017 5:00,0
 9/28/2017 6:00,0
 9/28/2017 7:00,0.15
 9/28/2017 8:00,8.76
 9/28/2017 9:00,0.02
 9/28/2017 10:00,0
 9/28/2017 11:00,0
 9/28/2017 12:00,0
 9/28/2017 13:00,0
 9/28/2017 14:00,0
 9/28/2017 15:00,0
 9/28/2017 16:00,0
 9/28/2017 17:00,0
 9/28/2017 18:00,0
 9/28/2017 19:00,0
 9/28/2017 20:00,0
 9/28/2017 21:00,0
 9/28/2017 22:00,0
 9/28/2017 23:00,0
 9/29/2017 0:00,0
 9/29/2017 1:00,0
 9/29/2017 2:00,0
 9/29/2017 3:00,0
 9/29/2017 4:00,0
 9/29/2017 5:00,0
 9/29/2017 6:00,0
 9/29/2017 7:00,0
 9/29/2017 8:00,0.31")
```

Step 2: parse date and time into new column `ts` containing timestamp:

```
mydt[, ts := as.POSIXct(date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")]
```

Step 3: compute time intervals and place dates in each interval according to the rules described in the question.

Define boundaries (in seconds, using epoch - see below) containing all dates from the frame starting and ending on the 9th hour:

```
epoch_start = as.integer(format(trunc(min(mydt$ts), "day") - (24 - 9) * 60 * 60, "%s"))
epoch_end = as.integer(format(trunc(max(mydt$ts), "day") + (24 + 9) * 60 * 60, "%s"))
```

Epoch is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 - for more details scroll down to *What is epoch time?* [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

Having computed the time interval encompassing all dates from the frame we can build our custom intervals of 24 hours starting with the 9th hour using base R:

```
time_seconds_intervals = seq(epoch_start, epoch_end, 60 * 60 * 24)
```

If you like to see what date and time behind any epoch value use package `anytime`:

```
anytime::anytime(epoch_start)
[1] "2017-09-26 09:00:00 CDT"

anytime::anytime(epoch_end)
[1] "2017-09-30 09:00:00 CDT"
```

and for the intervals we just built:

```
anytime::anytime(time_seconds_intervals)
[1] "2017-09-26 09:00:00 CDT" "2017-09-27 09:00:00 CDT" "2017-09-28 09:00:00 CDT" "2017-09-29 09:00:00 CDT"
[5] "2017-09-30 09:00:00 CDT"
```

Step 4: assign each row to an interval it belongs to using `findInterval` and create new column `day_group`

```
mydt[, day_group := findInterval(as.integer(format(ts, "%s")), time_seconds_intervals)]
```

Step 5: summarize with grouping by newly defined `day_group`

```
mydt[, .(date_group = min(ts), sum_pcp = sum(pcp)), by=day_group]
```

which produces:

```
   day_group          date_group sum_pcp
1:         2 2017-09-27 09:00:00    8.91
2:         3 2017-09-28 09:00:00    0.33
```

P.S.
I tried using `anytime` to parse dates in Step 2 above, but it failed due to single digit hours used in your strings, unfortunately. `anytime` is way faster than anything `lubridate` or base R offers to parse dates (many examples exist, here is one I posted recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183836/59470), but unless you change hours to always contain 2 digits like `09` it won't work on your data. In case you do change it that's how Step 2 would look:

```
mydt[, ts := anytime::anytime(date)]
```